# Terraform script Windows Module set account lockout policy & minimum password length Azure

Tags: windows, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am working on a Azure Terraform script, recently installed windows module when windows bootup there is no Account Lockout Policy & Minimum Password Length Policy set  by default, is there any way I can define in terraform script in windows module.
Thanks.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm" {
  name                 = var.vm_hostname
  count                = (var.is_windows_image || contains(list(var.vm_os_simple, var.vm_os_offer), "WindowsServer")) ? var.nb_instances : 0
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-windows[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

   settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "net accounts /minpwlen:8 && net accounts /maxpwage:45 && net accounts /minpwage:0 && net accounts /lockoutduration:30 && net accounts /lockoutthreshold:3 "    
      }
 SETTINGS

  
}
```

and I am getting error.

```
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.windowsservers.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]

Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension '`HOSTNAME'. Error message: \"Extension '' of Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript' version '1.0' faulted due to exception during extension processing\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSELinuxTroubleshoot "

  on ..\..\modules\windowsservers\main.tf line 194, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm":
 194: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm" {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm" {
  name                 = "${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
  count                = (var.is_windows_image || contains(list(var.vm_os_simple, var.vm_os_offer), "WindowsServer")) ? var.nb_instances : 0
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-windows[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

   settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command net accounts /minpwlen:8 && net accounts /maxpwage:45 && net accounts /minpwage:0 && net accounts /lockoutduration:30 && net accounts /lockoutthreshold:3 "    
      }
 SETTINGS

  
}
```

here is the piece of code which resolved my issue, this mistake i have been doing is using wrong extension which was for the Linux correct extension and code is pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure the Windows VM in the creation time, you can use the [cloud-init with the PowerShell script](https://cloudbase-init.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userdata.html#powershell). In terraform, you can use the [custom_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine#custom_data). And if you do not care when to configure, you can use the VM extension to do the things you want after creating the VM with resource [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension).

Comment: kindly look at my edits i have added a piece of code which i wanted to run on windows server after installation.

Comment: this directory is empty C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript\2.0.7

Comment: @MuhammadZaman What do you mean? You solve the problem yourself with the piece of the code you add?

Comment: the problem i was facing is that error and that error is because of wrong parameters these `publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"` parameters needs to change i was using wrong one as you can see in my original post.

Comment: @MuhammadZaman Yes, I can see that. You need to provide all the messages when you create the question. Everyone cannot help you solve the issue without enough information.

Comment: you are right i will make sure that again, but my question is correct because when you first answer and mentioned (Azure_virtual_machine_extension) part i did resolve my issue from there but while doing that i was getting issue so i posted that.